# Add images dynamically based on choice selected

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have the following layout which displays an image and a text string:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/number_icon"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/number_icon"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/letter_icon_margin_top" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/word_size_text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@drawable/borderaction" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

The `ivIcon` is displaying the images based on user input. It worked great when displaying one image per letter. But how do i fix the above layout so it displays the number of images based on user selection.

`@dimen` is used to change the view size based on the screen.

For example this is what is looking like when I use it for letter:

[image]

For the number, if the user chooses `5` the display should be:

[image]

If the user chooses `1` the display should be:

[image]

The code that is setting the image for the letter is:

```
ivLetterIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
ivLetterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple);
```

How would I accomplish the number images?

Would it be best to have a blank layout without the images and add the ImageView at runtim depending on the number and have it centered? This way the images(s) are centered to the parent view layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got an idea maybe you can try this out.
Try using GridView for displaying the number of apples by dynamically changing the column numbers and row numbers depending upon the screen. 
For ex, if gridView is the GridView and the entered number is 11, you can do this.

```
gridView.setNumberOfColumns(5);
gridView.setNumberOfRows(3);
```

so 5x3 can accomodate 15 elements which can fit in 11 easily.

Then inflate the custom view containing the Apple into the columns.

Comment: Only goes up to 10 but that's a good suggestion. I can set the GridLayout height and width to match parent centered and gridView.setNumberOfColumns(1) and gridView.setNumberOfRows(1) and add the image and do this for each other.

Comment: No such thing as .setNumberOfRows in GridView.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `layout_height` for the `ImageView` a fixed height

--edit--

```
int dp = TheFixedSize;
Resources resources = context.getResources();
DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
Imageview.setHeight(px);
```

Comment: I am designing for all screen size hence the @dimen used but thank you :)

Comment: You can do it in code then it will be the same size on all screen sizes like this (see edit)

Comment: I see what you mean. I think I will have to use GridLayout then as well